# Reverse a Long in C

Tags: c

How can I reverse the digits of a Long in C?

I only find how to do it with a Int.

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work with long numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int n, reverse = 0, remainder;

  printf("Enter an integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  while (n != 0) {
    remainder = n % 10;
    reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
    n /= 10;
  }

  printf("Reversed number = %d", reverse);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code uses `int`, not `long`. Show the code you used with `long`.

Comment: Also please describe what "doesn't work" means, more specifically. What results did you expect and what did you get instead?

Answer (score 2):

When handling this numerically, there is a risk that the result becomes out of range for the used data type. Using a `long long` to store the result may help, but the C Standard does not guarantee that the range of `long long` is larger than `long`.

A more robust method is to print the result to a string and then print that string in reverse order. In case of a negative number, the following code retains the sign as the first character in the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>  // CHAR_BIT

int main()
{
    long n = -12345;
    char str[2+(sizeof(n)*CHAR_BIT+2)/3];  // Need space for sign, terminating 0 and no more than 3 digits per 8 bits
    sprintf(str, "%ld", n);
    int begin = 0;
    if(str[0] == '-')
    {
        printf("-");
        begin = 1;
    }
    for(int i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= begin; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `long` instead of `int`. Use `abs` function in the `while` loop as below.

```
int main(void)
{
    long reverse, n;
    long long remainder = 0;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    
    int sign = n < 0 ? -1 : 1;

    while (n) {
        remainder = remainder * 10;
        remainder += labs(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
    reverse = remainder * sign;
    printf("Reversed number = %lld",reverse);
}
```

Comment: Corrected use `abs` to `labs` for for `long`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to take into account the sign.
2. Reversed number might not fit into your integer type. For example `2147483647` reversed will not fit in the int type and it will invoke undefined behaviour (UB). So you can simply use larger integer size.

```
long long reverse(long input) 
{

    long long result = 0;
    int sign = input < 0 ? -1 : 1;

    while (input) {
    result = result * 10;
    result += abs(input % 10);
    input /= 10;
    }

    return result * sign;
}

int main(void)
{
    long n;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    printf("Reversed number = %lld", reverse(n));
}
```